# How do you identify bugfix commits on QA environment with Git repository?

Tags: git, builds, qa, release

I got used to the following approach on bugfixing phase of the project development. The developer should add SVN commit number as a comment to the JIRA issue when resolving it. Latest artifact from CI-server shows build number which include major version, branch name and commit number. This approach helps QA easily to identify whether the bugfix was included in the latest build or not. Even when same issue was reopened and fixed again.

After moving from SVN to Git we lost incremental commit number. It is possible to solve this problem with tagging the code but tags are tied to the sprint numbers. And in case of the issue reopening this approach moves this issue resolving on the next sprint. But client is dissatisfied with the fact of having certain issue unfixed for a several sprints.

So, how do you identify bugfix commits in for QA environment?
Thanks.

**UPD: The question is NOT about linking issues to commits, but about ability of QAs figure out whether certain fix (ticket) is included in certain build just by looking on build number and ticket comments.**

Comment: "developer should add SVN commit number as a comment to the JIRA issue" -- why so? I ask because [FishEye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FishEye_%28software%29) links commit to JIRA issue automatically when commit message refers that issue (if memory serves it can do so for SVN, Git, Perforce etc)

Comment: As for the FishEye, company (or financial folks) can be against spending money on license for some software products which are not obviously effective from their point of view. As for the linking the issue to the commit, QA deal only with application. But even if they are familiar with FishEye and it is correctly set up and they see commits linked to the issues it doesn't help to tell whether the build contains certain fixes or not. It just points to the fact that certain fix was commited by developer.

Comment: I see, thanks. Consider [edit]ing the question to clarify this for other readers

Comment: I've edited my comment, Do you think I still need to edit the original question?

Comment: yes, because some readers tend to ignore comments

Comment: Paste the commit hash and/or commit message into the tracker? This is just about indicating when something is done with a papertrail, right?

Comment: QA has only build number on each page of the application and not familiar with git. Even if QA person is familiar with git it will take long enough time to dig in repo log to find out whether the fix is included or not.

Comment: I place my jira bug id# in the commit message when I interactively rebase my commits.  This is what I mean by workflow.

Comment: Putting ticket number to commit messages and even git branch names is an extremely good idea.

Comment: The notion that companies will pay $100,000+ per developer and then balk at a few tools that cost $1,000 - $10,000 per developer is very revealing.  It will reflect in whether the developers work as craftspeople with good tools.  or not.

Comment: How does something move from the repo to the QA environment in your environment?

Comment: A new tag is that what moves code from repo to QA.

Answer (score 2):

How about using tags to mark the commits ?

See this post about another user moving from SVN to GIT and facing similar issues to you, e.g. "As the svn revisions are simple numbers we can use them to extend the version numbers of our plugins and SDK builds"

More info at [How do you achieve a numeric versioning scheme with Git?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/141973/34069)

Comment: Yes, right. But this means that single issue may be resolved only once per tag and tag is usually tied to the sprint. So this means that it is not possible to reopen (and fix again) showstopper within same sprint.

Comment: @igorp1024 Why can't you have multiple tags per sprint? Have a tag per major build; I assume your build numbers increase monotonically? Say, I've built something from a commit I remember; after the build is done, I might `git tag` that commit with the build number. Maybe your build system can do this automatically. Tie fixes to builds / tags, not to commits. Tags are _very_ cheap. Just clean them up on the next sprint.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to flip around the work flow here -- rather than making the devs visit a different system to note commit numbers you can have the tracking system pull references out of the commit messages -- JIRA supports specially formed comments that do just this. See [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Processing+JIRA+issues+with+commit+messages) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

The general command that immediately jumps out at me is `git branch --contains`. Obviously that needs to be checked explicitly rather than at a glance.

But as long as you have at least one tag in your entire history and keep your history largely free of rebases, `git describe --tags` will give you a linear version.